# How to integrate jquery code without any code in the html file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to clear my code a little bit and I want to run my jquery code without any function call in the html file. My actual code is :

HTML:

```
<head>
    <script src="js/colorpick.js"></script>   
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            colorpick_start();
        });
    </script>
</head>
```

JS:

```
function colorpick_start() {
...
    }
```

But if I write for example an alert in the first row of the js without any function call, that works.

```
alert('test');

    function colorpick_start() {
    ...
        }
```

But this is not working for jquery selectors or something. Is there any solution to get my jquery working without code in the html file?

I want my html file to look like this, if this is possible:

```
<head>
    <script src="js/colorpick.js"></script>   
</head>
```

Comment: Loading jQuery as first script in your page, you can write at the bottom of your `colorpick` file the following: `$(colorpick_start);`. It should be triggered on DOM ready on the page.

Comment: you should call it at run time like `alert()` function. like this you can simply call your `colorpicker_start();`

Comment: If I put $(colorpick_start); to the first line it works for me! thanks a lot. If you want you could write that as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to achieve this:

```
<head>
   <script src="js/colorpick.js"></script>   
</head>
```

Move the document ready call to the js file you are referencing in your HTML file and make sure that the method called is present.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        colorpick_start();
});
```

This should so it.

Answer (score 2):

The

```
$(document).ready(function() {
```

Waits until the DOM is ready for selectors etc.

If you add the

```
$(document).ready(function() {
```

to your colorpick.js file it will wait for the DOM to be ready and then execute colorpick_start().

And believe me this catches out most people when they start using JQuery.

Comment: I knew about that and I thought i've done that like this a lot of times but its nor working in this case, I don't know why .But $(raumsettings_start); in the first line is working for me now.

Comment: Oh it works if I just call the function in .ready, i had replaced the function with the ready function...

Answer (score 1):

Put your script

```
<script src="js/colorpick.js"></script>
```

before `</body>` tag. This will ensure that your page is loaded fully before script starts.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        colorpick_start();
    });
```

this code is working because you are calling your function after document is loaded. document load is event. you can put your function on any event you want, but it wont start if you just define your function. You have to somehow call your function. example would be on click (or on document load)

```
  <div id="example"></div>


  $("#example").on('click', function () {

    your function here

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use that code:

```
$(function(){
  $('.colorpicker').val("colorpicker"); //or whatever you like
 });
```

[Plnkr example code](http://plnkr.co/edit/ihKXk2Zel7Q29EXhESPK)